# Implement a function which takes a list of numbers as an argument and returns true if that list only contains prime numbers and false if it does not

Tags: python

Any ideas? So far this just takes a single number and states if it is or isn't a prime number.

```
*a = input('enter a number: ')
    s = 0
    if a == 1:  
        print a, 'is a prime number'

    else : 

        for i in range (2, a ):

            if a%i == 0:
                print a,' is not a prime number'
                s = 'true'
                break

        if s == 0 : print a,' is a prime number'*
```

Comment: **Break the problem down into small steps**. Step 1: Write a function that takes a single number and tells you whether or not it's prime. Step 2: Write a function that takes a list of numbers and passes each one to the first function. Step 3: Write a function that creates a list from user input and passes it to the second function. Each of these can be tested and developed separately.

Comment: The number 1 is neither prime nor composite. Therefore, when `a == 1` you should say `is not a prime number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your code and turn it into a function that returns `True` or `False`:

```
def is_prime(a):

    a = input('enter a number: ')
        s = 0
        if a == 1:  
            print a, 'is a prime number'

        else : 

            for i in range (2, a ):

                if a%i == 0:
                    return False

            if s == 0 : return True
```

Then create a new function which takes the list and iterates through it with the `is_prime` (or whatever you decide to call it) function:

```
def all_prime(list_of_nums):
    for num in list_of_nums:
        if not is_prime(num):
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach would be testing each number on the list with some primality test. Rabin-Miller algorithm is one such test. You can find the details on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).

Comment: This is definitely worth a look, primality tests vary massively in how expensive they are to use and it's good to explore the options.

Comment: Considering that the question is phrased as a homework problem, I'm sure that the good old definition of “prime” as “not divisible by any number between 2 and floor(sqrt(x))” would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code you probably want in a simple version. Enter a list in the format: 1,3,4,5,6... etc

```
import math

a = input('enter a list of numbers seperated by commas: ')
flag_primes = False
primes = []

def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2: 
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2))

for num in a:
    if is_prime(num):
        flag_primes = True
        primes.append(num)

if flag_primes:
    print "The list contains the following primes:", primes
else:
    print "No primes found in list!"
```

Answer (score 0):

If the max of the list is reasonably bounded, you may construct a [Sieve of Erathostenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)..

There is a little modification of the straightforward implementation taken from [rossettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

```
def isprime_upto(limit):
    is_prime = [False] * 2 + [True] * (limit - 1) 
    for n in range(int(limit**0.5 + 1.5)): # stop at ``sqrt(limit)``
        if is_prime[n]:
            for i in range(n*n, limit+1, n):
                is_prime[i] = False
    return is_prime
```

Then you can check if every element in a list if a prime with something like:

```
def all_primes(list):
    sieve = isprime_upto(max(list))
    is_prime = [sieve[x] for x in list]
    return all(is_prime)
```